# SonarQube for MSBuild not reporting quality issues

Tags: sonarqube

I'm doing a POC on SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, and as part of it I created a simple c# project with many code snippets which should be flagged as bugs or code smell.  I even took examples straight from the defined rules which are active in the Sonar Way Quality profile that I'm using.

It appears that SonarQube is not recognizing these issues.  Looking at our SonarQube instance the code is getting there successfully, but no issues are getting reported.

Here is an example of code that should be caught as a bug in the quality profile "Sonar Way" (S3168 - "async" methods should not return "void").  The file containing this is called "BadClass.cs", which can be seen in the log output.

```
class HttpPrinter
{
    private string content;
    public async void CallNetwork(string url) //Noncompliant
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task PrintContent(string url)  // works correctly if web request finishes in under 1 second, otherwise content will be null
    {
        CallNetwork(url);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.Write(content);
    }

}
```

Here is the log output for the scans:

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.3.1
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Default properties file was found at C:\sonarscanner-msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarscanner-msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
10:02:38.789  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
10:02:38.792  Not running under TeamBuild
10:02:38.792  Analysis base directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube
Build directory: 
Bin directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\bin
Config directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\conf
Output directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out
Config file: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
Setting analysis property: sonar.visualstudio.enable=false
Using longest common projects root path as project base directory: 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube'.
WARNING: File 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.1\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll' is not located under the root directory 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube' and will not be analyzed.
File was referenced by the following projects: 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube\TestSonarQube.csproj'.
WARNING: File 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.1\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll' is not located under the root directory 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube' and will not be analyzed.
File was referenced by the following projects: 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube\TestSonarQube.csproj'.
WARNING: File 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.1\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll' is not located under the root directory 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube' and will not be analyzed.
File was referenced by the following projects: 'C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube\TestSonarQube.csproj'.
Dumping content of sonar-project.properties
------------------------------------------------------------------------
sonar.projectKey=test.sonar.integration
sonar.working.directory=C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\.sonarqube\\out\\.sonar
sonar.projectBaseDir=C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube

45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.projectKey=test.sonar.integration:45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847
45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.projectName=TestSonarQube
45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.projectBaseDir=C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube
45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.sourceEncoding=utf-8
45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.sources=
45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847.sonar.tests=\
"C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube\\BadClass.cs",\
"C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube\\Foo.cs",\
"C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube\\UnitTest1.cs",\
"C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube\\Properties\\AssemblyInfo.cs",\
"C:\\code\\vsts\\TestSonarQube\\src\\TestSonarQube\\packages.config"

sonar.host.url=http://MyServer:9000
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.visualstudio.enable=false

sonar.modules=45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Writing processing summary to C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
Setting environment variable 'SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS'. Value: -Xmx1024m
Executing file C:\sonarscanner-msbuild\sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
  Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties --embedded <sensitive data removed>
  Working directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src
  Timeout (ms):-1
  Process id: 14420
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonarscanner-msbuild\sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
10:02:39.124 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
10:02:39.127 INFO: Java 1.8.0_181 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
10:02:39.128 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
10:02:39.128 INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
10:02:39.252 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
10:02:39.252 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
10:02:39.252 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
10:02:39.252 DEBUG: init keystore
10:02:39.253 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
10:02:39.601 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\jwaide\.sonar\cache
10:02:39.602 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\jwaide\.sonar\cache
10:02:39.602 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\jwaide\.sonar\cache\_tmp
10:02:39.605 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
10:02:39.653 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
10:02:39.653 DEBUG: Download: http://scsonara01:9000/batch/index
10:02:39.790 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
10:02:39.798 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
10:02:39.805 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
10:02:39.811 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
10:02:39.811 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
10:02:39.814 INFO: SonarQube server 7.2.1
10:02:39.814 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
10:02:39.815 DEBUG: Work directory: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
10:02:39.816 DEBUG: Execution execute
10:02:40.089 INFO: Publish mode
10:02:40.201 INFO: Load global settings
10:02:40.690 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=483ms
10:02:40.716 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=515ms
10:02:40.721 INFO: Server id: AWU0ZxrMOjUK0oLgK7-R
10:02:40.730 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\jwaide\.sonar\cache
10:02:40.909 INFO: Load/download plugins
10:02:40.909 INFO: Load plugins index
10:02:41.312 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/plugins/installed | time=403ms
10:02:41.364 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=455ms
10:02:41.379 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=470ms
10:02:41.405 DEBUG: Plugins:
10:02:41.405 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.2.0.5463 (csharp)
10:02:41.406 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.10.0.2131 (python)
10:02:41.406 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.4.0.14284 (java)
10:02:41.406 DEBUG:   * LDAP 2.2.0.608 (ldap)
10:02:41.406 DEBUG:   * Git 1.4.1.1128 (scmgit)
10:02:41.406 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.5.1.1452 (xml)
10:02:41.407 DEBUG:   * SonarGo 1.1.0.1612 (go)
10:02:41.407 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.7.0.2893 (typescript)
10:02:41.407 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 4.1.0.6085 (javascript)
10:02:41.419 INFO: Loaded core extensions: 
10:02:41.696 INFO: Process project properties
10:02:41.705 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=9ms
10:02:41.725 INFO: Load project repositories
10:02:42.150 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=lighthouse.sonar.integration | time=424ms
10:02:42.213 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=488ms
10:02:42.288 DEBUG: Available languages:
10:02:42.288 DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
10:02:42.288 DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
10:02:42.288 DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
10:02:42.289 DEBUG:   * XML => "xml"
10:02:42.289 DEBUG:   * Go => "go"
10:02:42.289 DEBUG:   * TypeScript => "ts"
10:02:42.289 DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
10:02:42.296 INFO: Load quality profiles
10:02:42.705 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=lighthouse.sonar.integration | time=407ms
10:02:42.730 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=434ms
10:02:42.747 INFO: Load active rules
10:02:43.165 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0HsOjUK0oLgK8lG&p=1&ps=500 | time=416ms
10:02:43.666 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0MGOjUK0oLgK8tS&p=1&ps=500 | time=423ms
10:02:44.127 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0QPOjUK0oLgK8zu&p=1&ps=500 | time=403ms
10:02:44.550 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0Q-OjUK0oLgK80O&p=1&ps=500 | time=420ms
10:02:44.975 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0UJOjUK0oLgK85_&p=1&ps=500 | time=412ms
10:02:45.409 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0YyOjUK0oLgK8_h&p=1&ps=500 | time=414ms
10:02:45.833 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWU0Z0ZxOjUK0oLgK9A3&p=1&ps=500 | time=421ms
10:02:45.860 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=3113ms
10:02:45.863 INFO: Load metrics repository
10:02:46.265 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/metrics/search?f=name,description,direction,qualitative,custom&ps=500&p=1 | time=402ms
10:02:46.293 INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=431ms
10:02:46.324 INFO: Project key: lighthouse.sonar.integration
10:02:46.325 INFO: Project base dir: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube
10:02:46.326 DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
10:02:46.327 INFO: -------------  Scan TestSonarQube
10:02:46.451 INFO: Load server rules
10:02:46.883 DEBUG: GET 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=432ms
10:02:46.979 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=528ms
10:02:47.009 INFO: Base dir: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube
10:02:47.009 INFO: Working dir: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\lighthouse.sonar.integration_lighthouse.sonar.integration_45617122-FB02-405F-B359-BA0B2E0B1847
10:02:47.011 INFO: Test paths: BadClass.cs, Foo.cs, UnitTest1.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, packages.config
10:02:47.011 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
10:02:47.088 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
10:02:47.088 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
10:02:47.088 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
10:02:47.089 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
10:02:47.089 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Go were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.go : **/*.go
10:02:47.089 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
10:02:47.089 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
10:02:47.089 INFO: Language is forced to cs
10:02:47.102 DEBUG: Initializers : 
10:02:47.103 INFO: Index files
10:02:47.115 DEBUG: 'BadClass.cs' indexed as test with language 'cs'
10:02:47.118 DEBUG: 'Foo.cs' indexed as test with language 'cs'
10:02:47.121 DEBUG: 'UnitTest1.cs' indexed as test with language 'cs'
10:02:47.122 DEBUG: 'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' indexed as test with language 'cs'
10:02:47.123 INFO: 4 files indexed
10:02:47.124 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
10:02:47.847 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.847 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.848 DEBUG: 'Import external issues report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.857 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.858 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.859 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:47.859 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.859 DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.860 DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.860 DEBUG: 'PythonXUnitSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.860 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.861 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.861 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.861 DEBUG: 'XML Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.861 DEBUG: 'SonarGo' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.861 DEBUG: 'Go Unit Test Report' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.862 DEBUG: 'Import of go vet issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.862 DEBUG: 'Import of Golint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.862 DEBUG: 'Import of GoMetaLinter issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.863 DEBUG: 'Import of TSLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.863 DEBUG: 'Import of ESLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.864 DEBUG: 'SonarTS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.864 DEBUG: 'SonarTS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.864 DEBUG: 'SonarJS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.865 DEBUG: 'SonarJS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:47.868 DEBUG: Sensors : C# Properties -> SonarJavaXmlFileSensor
10:02:47.869 INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
10:02:47.870 INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
10:02:47.870 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
10:02:47.871 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
10:02:47.886 DEBUG: 'BadClass.cs' generated metadata as test  with charset 'UTF-8'
10:02:47.887 DEBUG: 'Foo.cs' generated metadata as test  with charset 'UTF-8'
10:02:47.978 DEBUG: 'Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs' generated metadata as test  with charset 'UTF-8'
10:02:47.981 DEBUG: 'UnitTest1.cs' generated metadata as test  with charset 'UTF-8'
10:02:47.984 INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
10:02:47.985 INFO: 1 files to be analyzed
10:02:48.022 DEBUG: Blame file src/TestSonarQube/BadClass.cs
10:02:48.108 DEBUG: Unable to blame file BadClass.cs. No blame info at line 4. Is file committed? [Author: PersonIdent[Not Committed Yet, , Tue Aug 28 10:02:48 2018 -0700] Source commit: null]
10:02:48.112 INFO: 0/1 files analyzed
10:02:48.116 INFO: -------------  Scan lighthouse.sonar.integration
10:02:48.151 INFO: Base dir: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\TestSonarQube
10:02:48.151 INFO: Working dir: C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
10:02:48.151 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
10:02:48.173 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
10:02:48.173 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
10:02:48.174 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
10:02:48.174 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
10:02:48.174 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Go were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.go : **/*.go
10:02:48.175 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
10:02:48.175 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
10:02:48.176 INFO: Language is forced to cs
10:02:48.181 DEBUG: Initializers : 
10:02:48.181 INFO: Index files
10:02:48.182 INFO: 0 files indexed
10:02:48.226 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'Import external issues report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'C# Properties' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.227 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'PythonXUnitSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'XML Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'SonarGo' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'Go Unit Test Report' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'Import of go vet issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'Import of Golint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.228 DEBUG: 'Import of GoMetaLinter issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'Import of TSLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'Import of ESLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'SonarTS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'SonarTS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'SonarJS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.229 DEBUG: 'SonarJS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.230 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.230 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.230 DEBUG: 'Import external issues report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.231 DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.232 DEBUG: 'PythonXUnitSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.232 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.232 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.232 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.232 DEBUG: 'XML Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.234 DEBUG: 'SonarGo' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.234 DEBUG: 'Go Unit Test Report' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.234 DEBUG: 'Import of go vet issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'Import of Golint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'Import of GoMetaLinter issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'Import of TSLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'Import of ESLint issues' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'SonarTS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.235 DEBUG: 'SonarTS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.236 DEBUG: 'SonarJS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.236 DEBUG: 'SonarJS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:02:48.236 DEBUG: Sensors : SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> C# -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
10:02:48.236 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
10:02:48.236 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
10:02:48.237 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
10:02:48.238 DEBUG: No files to analyze. Skip Sensor.
10:02:48.238 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
10:02:48.238 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
10:02:48.238 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
10:02:48.238 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
10:02:48.238 DEBUG: org.sonar.scanner.cpd.deprecated.DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
10:02:48.238 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language cs
10:02:48.238 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
10:02:48.239 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
10:02:48.243 INFO: CPD calculation finished
10:02:48.355 INFO: Analysis report generated in 109ms, dir size=34 KB
10:02:48.378 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 22ms, zip size=11 KB
10:02:48.378 INFO: Analysis report generated in C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\scanner-report
10:02:48.378 DEBUG: Upload report
10:02:48.786 DEBUG: POST 200 http://scsonara01:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=lighthouse.sonar.integration | time=407ms
10:02:48.794 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 416ms
10:02:48.799 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://scsonara01:9000/dashboard?id=lighthouse.sonar.integration
10:02:48.800 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
10:02:48.800 INFO: More about the report processing at http://scsonara01:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWWBfN2quxxeJ5jeK02H
10:02:48.810 DEBUG: Report metadata written to C:\code\vsts\TestSonarQube\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\report-task.txt
10:02:48.812 DEBUG: Post-jobs : 
10:02:48.817 INFO: Task total time: 7.398 s
10:02:48.909 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:02:48.909 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
10:02:48.909 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:02:48.909 INFO: Total time: 9.845s
10:02:48.961 INFO: Final Memory: 12M/306M
10:02:48.962 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Process returned exit code 0
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
10:02:49.024  Creating a summary markdown file...
10:02:49.028  Analysis results: http://scsonara01:9000/dashboard/index/lighthouse.sonar.integration
10:02:49.029  Post-processing succeeded.
```

Any help in troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the same code when browsing in the portal? Check also the profile used and if this rule is activated in that profile.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes on both counts.  The code is on the portal, and this is active on the Sonar Way profile.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897445/sonarqube-new-code-definition) SO question and answer. Maybe related to your issue?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I hadn't seen that.  However, I have been adding new, bad code as I test, and the leak period hasn't terminated since the creation of the project (2 days ago.)  I appreciate the suggestion though :)  I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Do you see any other issues reported? SonarQube isn't a perfect tool so it could also be a bug,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up that the issue was with the version of MSBuild that I was using.  Using MSBuild 15 did the trick for me.
Here is the link that pointed me in the right location:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/1828#issuecomment-418125650

Now the analysis is happening successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a project that does not have "Test" in the project name or path.

The specification for each rule determines whether it runs against product code, test code, or both. The Scanner for MSBuild decides whether a project is a test project or not by looking at a number of factors e.g. the project type, and the project name.

I'd guess that the Scanner is classifying your project as a test project 
so the rules you've picked aren't being run against it.

If you look under the .sonarqube directory you'll find a projectinfo.xml file for each MSBuild project that was analysed. If you look in that file you'll see whether the Scanner classified the project as a test project or not.

Comment: I checked the projectinfo.xml file, and it did indeed mark the project as "Test" (+1).  I then created a brand new project with no occurrence of "test" in any of the names, and while it actually marked the project as a "Product" type, it still didn't catch any of the code smell. Example:         
    
public string Append(string beginning, string end)
        {
            return $"{beginning.ToString()}{end.ToString()}"; //redundant tostring
        }